# Convert TextBoxFor to LabelFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.STPData.ProjectName, new { @class = "economicTextBox", disabled="disabled", propertyName = "STPData.ProjectName", onchange = "UpdateField(this);" })%>
```

When I just change it to LabelFor directly, it yells at me for not having the right amount of parameters. Then if I take the long second param out of there, it doesn't show the right string on the front end.

What's the correct way to create a Label from this TextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LabelFor needs you to define an attribute against your property to put in the friendly text.

So in your `STPData.ProjectName` property you need to add the attribute: `[DisplayName("YOUr friendlyname goes here")]` (example below):

```
public class STPData
{
    [DisplayName("Name For Project")]
    public string ProjectName {get;set;}
}
```

So when you call

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.STPData.ProjectName) %>
```

The Display name is used.

Alternatively you could use `.Label(` and then you can define the Control to attach to and the text to display that way.

Comment: In the attribute for the friendly name, could I do something like this.ProjectName? or would that not work. I want it to be a label of the actual project name, not the label for that property. you know?

Comment: Ah-ha then you dont want to use Label for. `<%= Html.Encode(Model.STPData.ProjectName)%>` is what you need to look at. Labels in MVC should always be associated with a control to work correctly.